# 'restoreProgress' is inaccessible due to 'private' level protection - swift

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I used an Library named "UICircularProgressRing" in my Demo Project and it was working completely fine. But when I try to use that library in my real project, it throws errors like

"**/Users/FitnyTech/Desktop/BBF/Pods/UICircularProgressRing/src/UICircularProgressRing/UICircularProgressRing.swift:1008:68: 'restoreProgress' is inaccessible due to 'private' protection level"**

How to solve this Issue?

Comment: the error already solves it... it says `private`, so make it `public`

Comment: [Change line 1264 from private to public](https://github.com/luispadron/UICircularProgressRing/blob/master/src/UICircularProgressRing/UICircularProgressRing.swift#L1264)

Comment: but it is inside the library file, I can't change the files without forking it right?

Comment: The method is private for a reason. Figure out what public method you should call to get the same effect. Find out what calls `restoreProgress`

Comment: @WarrenBurton I just unlocked the pod file and changed private to public, will it cause problem in future?

Comment: Who knows. The original dev made it private for a reason. It might not exist in a future version of the pod. You might try using `continueProgress` instead which is `public` and appears to do a lot of things.

Answer (score 3):

first check swift versions on both project. Then clean your project `shift+cmd+k`, delete all files in derived data (File -> Workspace Settings-> DerivedData) and then launch your app

Comment: will try and let you know, what is meant by Derived Data

Comment: Just go to that path and you will see Derived Data

Comment: light gray text 'Developer/Xcode/DerivedData' and after that text you will see arrow, press at this arrow and folder will open and after that clean all in folder name "DerivedData"

Comment: I exactly did all the things as you said, but still the errors are there

Comment: I just changed the private to public in cocoa pod file, will it affect my codebase in future?

Comment: every time after 'pod update/install' you will have problem

Answer (score 0):

Migrating my code from swift 3.0 to 4.0 solved the issue.